# incomplete python code not executing

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am an absolute beginner and learning python, I wrote a code but it's incomplete and I have no clue about the missing part. Can anyone help please?

```
def my_age_months(x):
    a = my_age_months(36)
    return (x*12)
    print("a:")
    print(a)
    if a > 400:
        return "you are not young"
    else:
        return "you are young"
```

Comment: Please format the code it's obscure. And what wrror are you facing

Answer (score 5):

What you wanna look out for is indentation.
Python code is all about correct indentation
and white space is important so structure your code nicely
as python is about readable and neat code.
Best of Luck, Happy Coding :)

```
def my_age_months(x):
  return (x*12)

a = my_age_months(36)

print("a:")
print(a)

if a > 400:
    return "you are not young"
else:
    return "you are young"
```

Answer (score 0):

You put

```
a = my_age_months(36)
```

in the def function, which will make it not work.

I presume you want is this:

```
def my_age_months(x):
    return (x*12)

    print("a:")
    print(a)
    if a > 400:
        return "you are not young"
    else:
        return "you are young"
my_age_months(36)
```